# How do I make a JSON object with multiple arrays?

Tags: json

I've never used JSON before so I'm not familiar with its syntax.

At the moment I have multiple arrays containing different pieces of data.

I would like to create one JSON object, that contains the multiple arrays each with several pieces of data.

E.g.

An object called cars, containing multiple arrays each for a different make of car. In each array would be the model of car along with some other types of data e.g. number of doors (doesn't really matter its just a fictional example.)

It would be greatly appreciated if someone explained the syntax with an example.

Comment: You don't work with JSON directly, except in very rare circumstances. You work with native data structures, then use a library to convert that structure to a JSON string.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

On the outermost level, a JSON object starts with a `{` and end with a `}`.

Sample data:

```
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Skyline", "doors":2}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
        ]
    }
}
```

If the JSON is assigned to a variable called data, then accessing it would be like the following:

```
data.cars['Nissan'][0].model   // Sentra
data.cars['Nissan'][1].model   // Maxima
data.cars['Nissan'][2].doors   // 2

for (var make in data.cars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.cars[make].length; i++) {
        var model = data.cars[make][i].model;
        var doors = data.cars[make][i].doors;
        alert(make + ', ' + model + ', ' + doors);
    }
}
```

Another approach (using an associative array for car models rather than an indexed array):

```
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": {
            "Sentra": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
            "Maxima": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
        },
        "Ford": {
            "Taurus": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
            "Escort": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
        }
    }
}

data.cars['Nissan']['Sentra'].doors   // 4
data.cars['Nissan']['Maxima'].doors   // 4
data.cars['Nissan']['Maxima'].transmission   // automatic

for (var make in data.cars) {
    for (var model in data.cars[make]) {
        var doors = data.cars[make][model].doors;
        alert(make + ', ' + model + ', ' + doors);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Correction: A JSON object starts with `{` and ends with `}`, but it's also valid to have a JSON array (on the outermost level), that starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

Also, significant syntax errors in the original JSON data have been corrected: All key names in a JSON object must be in double quotes, and all string values in a JSON object or a JSON array must be in double quotes as well.

**See:**

- [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)
- [JSONLint - The JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Just to clarify: is this an object? Does it need [] brackets?

Comment: The JSON data is an object (basically an associative array). Indexed arrays use square brackets, `[0,1,2]`, while associative arrays use curly braces, `{x:1,y:2,z:3}`. Any of the data within the outermost object can be either type of array, but the outermost object itself has to use curly braces.

Comment: And how would I loop through the towns in this: http://pastebin.com/qyQ2Y9sn so that I could access the lat and lng.

Comment: `for (var town in markers.towns) { alert(markers.towns[town].lat) }`

Comment: Sure, no problem :) I added some examples of iterating through the JSON data in both examples above.

Comment: How would you access the make of car in the first example?

Comment: If you mean the model (since the make is accessed the same in both examples), there's no direct way to access the model, which is why I added the second example. In the first one, you have to iterate through through the data until you find the model you're looking for.

Comment: See the notes at the end of the answer above. There were significant mistakes that have been corrected.

Comment: Two mistakes: Put "towns" in double quotes, and remove the last comma (there should only be a comma between elements, not at the end of the last element).

Comment: Now my code doesn't work, do I still reference to it in the same way? `var town in markers.towns` and `markers.towns[town].lat`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13054/discussion-between-matt-coughlin-and-harry)

Comment: @MattCoughlin is datatype of data here JSONObject ?

Comment: There is a typo in the second code example:
`data.cars['Nissan'][2].doors` should be `data.cars['Nissan'][1].doors`.
I cannot edit the answer because I need to edit at least 6 characters

Comment: The correction sentence at the bottom solved my issue ty. all i needed was an array of elements, eg [1,2,3]

Answer (score 24):

A good book I'm reading: Professional JavaScript for Web Developers by Nicholas C. Zakas 3rd Edition has the following information regarding JSON Syntax:

> "JSON Syntax allows the representation of three types of values".

Regarding the one you're interested in, Arrays it says:

> "Arrays are represented in JSON using array literal notation from JavaScript. For example, this is an array in JavaScript:

```
var values = [25, "hi", true];
```

> You can represent this same array in JSON using a similar syntax:

```
[25, "hi", true]
```

> Note the absence of a variable or a semicolon. Arrays and objects can be used together to represent more complex collections of data, such as:

```
{
    "books":
              [
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C. Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 3,
                    "year": 2011
                },
                {
                    "title": "Professional JavaScript",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C.Zakas"
                    ],
                    "edition": 2,
                    "year": 2009
                },
                {
                    "title": "Professional Ajax",
                    "authors": [
                        "Nicholas C. Zakas",
                        "Jeremy McPeak",
                        "Joe Fawcett"
                    ],
                    "edition": 2,
                    "year": 2008
                }
              ]
}
```

> This Array contains a number of objects representing books, Each object has several keys, one of which is "authors", which is another array. Objects and arrays are typically top-level parts of a JSON data structure (even though this is not required) and can be used to create a large number of data structures."

To serialize (convert) a JavaScript object into a JSON string you can use the JSON object stringify() method. For the example from Mark Linus answer:

```
var cars = [{
    color: 'gray',
    model: '1',
    nOfDoors: 4
    },
    {
    color: 'yellow',
    model: '2',
    nOfDoors: 4
}];
```

cars is now a JavaScript object. To convert it into a JSON object you could do:

```
var jsonCars = JSON.stringify(cars);
```

Which yields:

```
"[{"color":"gray","model":"1","nOfDoors":4},{"color":"yellow","model":"2","nOfDoors":4}]"
```

To do the opposite, convert a JSON object into a JavaScript object (this is called parsing), you would use the parse() method. Search for those terms if you need more information... or get the book, it has many examples.

Comment: In the above example "edition" & "year" should be in quotes - https://jsonlint.co.uk/ won't validate otherwise

Answer (score 4):

Another example:

```
[  
[  
    {  
        "@id":1,
        "deviceId":1,
        "typeOfDevice":"1",
        "state":"1",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":2,
        "deviceId":3,
        "typeOfDevice":"3",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":3,
        "deviceId":4,
        "typeOfDevice":"jÃºuna",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":4,
        "deviceId":5,
        "typeOfDevice":"nffjnff",
        "state":"Regular",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":5,
        "deviceId":6,
        "typeOfDevice":"44",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":6,
        "deviceId":7,
        "typeOfDevice":"rr",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":7,
        "deviceId":8,
        "typeOfDevice":"j",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":8,
        "deviceId":9,
        "typeOfDevice":"55",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":9,
        "deviceId":10,
        "typeOfDevice":"5",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    },
    {  
        "@id":10,
        "deviceId":11,
        "typeOfDevice":"5",
        "state":"Excelent",
        "assigned":true
    }
],
1
]
```

### Read the array's

```
$.each(data[0], function(i, item) {
         data[0][i].deviceId + data[0][i].typeOfDevice  + data[0][i].state +  data[0][i].assigned 
    });
```

---

Use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to understand the JSON code better

Comment: What is with the 1 on the second last line of your json?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Second element of outermost array?

Answer (score 2):

```
var cars = [
    manufacturer: [
        {
            color: 'gray',
            model: '1',
            nOfDoors: 4
        },
        {
            color: 'yellow',
            model: '2',
            nOfDoors: 4
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: What about having a car manufacturer array inside the object? so `cars` > `manufacturer` > `model, color, doors`. (arrays within arrays within an object)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I would like to add another JSON example along with Java code.

#### Example JSON:

```
{
  "cars": [
      {
        "model": "Nissan",
        "code": "1",
        "id": "12",
        "properties": {"color": "red", "doors": "4", "engine": "best", "price": "500", "is_electric": "false"}
      },
      {
        "model": "Tesla",
        "code": "2",
        "id": "13",
        "properties": {"color": "grey", "doors": "4", "engine": "best", "price": "800", "is_electric": "true"}
      },
      {
        "model": "Kia",
        "code": "3",
        "id": "14",
        "properties": {"color": "green", "doors": "4", "engine": "diesel", "price": "900", "is_electric": "false"}
      }
  ]
}
```

- `"cars"` represents a JSON array
- Each JSON object inside of `"cars"` array describes a car using `"properties"` JSON object and other fields.

  - For sure, each car may have some unique `"id"`, `"code"` and `"model"` name.
  - Additionally, the `"properties"` object helps to describe another set of car characteristics.
    It consists of `"color"`, `"doors"`, `"engine"`, `"price"`, and `"is_electric"` fields.

#### Java code:

This code manipulates the JSON object with the help of `org.json` library.

1. `jsonObject` stores the whole JSON string.
2. Then we retrieve the highest level object `"cars"` into `jsonArray` variable.
3. Using `for`-loop we iterate over the JSON array and print each car's JSON data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String carsJson = "insert_your_json"; //TODO

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(carsJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars");
    int length = jsonArray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printData(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
    }
}

private static void printData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    String message = "Id: %s\nModel: %s\nCode: %s\n" +
            "Properties:\n\tcolor: %s\n\tdoors: %s\n\tengine: %s\n\tprice: %s\n\tis_electric: %s\n\n";
    JSONObject properties = jsonObject.getJSONObject("properties");

    System.out.printf(message, 
            jsonObject.get("id"), jsonObject.get("model"), jsonObject.get("code"),
            properties.get("color"), properties.get("doors"), properties.get("engine"), 
            properties.get("price"), properties.get("is_electric"));
}
```

Output:

```
Id: 12
Model: Nissan
Code: 1
Properties:
    color: red
    doors: 4
    engine: best
    price: 500
    is_electric: false

Id: 13
Model: Tesla
Code: 2
Properties:
    color: grey
    doors: 4
    engine: best
    price: 800
    is_electric: true

Id: 14
Model: Kia
Code: 3
Properties:
    color: green
    doors: 4
    engine: diesel
    price: 900
    is_electric: false
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Using the below method pass any value which is an array:

Use:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>


Input parameter: URL, like 
Example: "$node.[any int value of array].anyKeyWhichInArray"
Example: "$.cars.Nissan.[0].model"





    public String getAnyValueFromResponseBody(String jsonBody, String url) {
        String value = "";
        try {
          value = JsonPath.read(jsonBody, url).toString();
          System.out.println(value);
        } catch (Exception var6) {
          System.error.println("unable to parse "+url);
        }
        return value;
      }
```