# Json with C++ - How to create an array/list of objects in code(not in text format)

Tags: c++, json

I want something like the below in json c++ code

```
{
"Numofbooks": 2
"book1": { "title":"saaas", "ISBN":234234, "author":"sdjjh"}
"book2": { "title":"fdfrg", "ISBN":8978, "author":"dttt"}
}
```

I have already checked this link and it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197818/how-do-i-make-a-json-object-with-multiple-arrays/11197949), but it doesnt show how to do it in C++ code.
I am using this JSON CPP library, http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net.

So to code I should do something like belo

```
Json::objectvalue obj;
obj[numofbooks] = 2;
```

Next how do I fill this list of book1 and book2?? I am not getting this..Please advice

Answer (score 2):

```
Json::Value arr(Json::arrayValue);

arr.append("a");
arr.append("b");
arr.append(1000);

Json::Value obj;

obj["a"] = "aa";
obj["b"] = 1000;
obj["c"] = arr;

std::cout << arr.toStyledString() << std::endl;
std::cout << obj.toStyledString() << std::endl;
```