# Unable to deserialize Json string array of arrays into object when using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

i am using Newtonsoft.Json and trying to deserialize an array of arrays Json string into C# object i created.

This is the json string -

```
[4615,4618,4619,4626,4615,4626,4631,4636,4637],[4615,4618,4619,4626,4615,4626,4631,4636,4637],[4615,4618,4619,4626,4615,4626,4631,4636,4637]
```

This is my object model -

```
  public class NumberMatrix
    {
        public List<int> NumberIDs { get; set; }

        public NumberMatrix()
        {
            this.NumberIDs = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

This is how i try to convert -

```
var numbers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Numbers"];
var numberIDsMatrix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NumberMatrix>>(numbers);
```

i tried to deserialize the json in few ways, and got different errors. is it possible to deserialize this json string? how?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, you need to surround it with `[...]` for example.

Comment: Take a look here for JSON formatting for arrays [stackoverflow.com/questions/11197818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197818/how-do-i-make-a-json-object-with-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

That isn't valid JSON, you need to surround it with `[...]` for example. You could do this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<int>>>($"[{numbers}]");
```

Comment: Its working. But what u wrote and what i wrote is the same.

Comment: How is it the same?